# VBA Loop to Conditionally Format showing Type Mismatch bug

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

I have an excel sheet with 4 columns, and I want to loop through the column and if (Column D/Column C) <> (Column B/Column A), highlight all 4 cells. I'm getting a Type Mismatch running the following and not sure why?

```
Sub Check()

Dim ValA as Variant 
Dim ValB as Variant 
Dim ValC as Variant 
Dim ValD as Variant 
Dim ColA as Long 
Dim ColB as Long 
Dim ColC as Long
Dim ColD as Long

Set ValA = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("A", lookat:=xlWhole)    
ColA = ValA.Column

 Set ValB = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("B", lookat:=xlWhole)    
ColB = ValB.Column

 Set ValC = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("C", lookat:=xlWhole)    
ColC = ValC.Column

 Set ValD = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("D", lookat:=xlWhole)    
ColD = ValD.Column


LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Loop

For i = 2 to LastRow
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(i,ColD).Value/ActiveSheet.Cells(i,ColC).Value <> ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Value/ActiveSheet(i, ColA).Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColD).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a conditional format to do your conditional formatting?

Comment: ColA, ColB, ColC are variants

Comment: To be honest with you, I dont even know how to do it in CF...

Comment: @QHarr do you mean they should be variants? what about ColD?

Answer (score 0):

With `Dim ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD as Long` only the last is a Long and the others are implicitly variants. You would need to declare each as Long.

Also, ValA etc are Ranges and you want to access the Column property of the Range object.

```
Dim ValA As Range
Dim ValB As Range
Dim ValC As Range
Dim ValD as Range
Dim ColA As Long
Dim ColB As Long
Dim ColC As Long
Dim ColD as Long
```

You will also need some error handling in case Find doesn't return a match object.

For example, If `"A"` not found in row 1 then `ValA` is Nothing and you will get an error when trying to access the column so handle this with a `If Not ValA Is Nothing`:

```
Set ValA = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("A", lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not ValA Is Nothing Then  
    ColA = ValA.Column
End If
```

Something like (and i haven't tested this):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

Dim ValA As Range
Dim ValB As Variant
Dim ValC As Variant
Dim ValD As Variant
Dim ColA As Long
Dim ColB As Long
Dim ColC As Long
Dim ColD As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

Set ValA = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("A", lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not ValA Is Nothing Then
    ColA = ValA.Column
End If

Set ValB = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("B", lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not ValB Is Nothing Then
    ColB = ValB.Column
End If

Set ValC = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("C", lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not ValC Is Nothing Then
    ColC = ValC.Column
End If

Set ValD = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("D", lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not ValD Is Nothing Then
    ColD = ValD.Column
End If

lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Loop

If ColA > 0 And ColB > 0 And ColC > 0 And ColD > 0 Then

    For i = 2 To lastRow

        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColD).Value / ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Value <> ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Value / ActiveSheet(i, ColA).Value Then

            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColA).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColB).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColD).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        End If

    Next i

 Else

     MsgBox "Matches weren't found for A,B,C and D in row 1."

End If

End Sub
```

`Option Explicit` at the top forces you to declare all your variables and checks the type. Great for catching errors early.

How you choose to handle values not being found is up to you. I have given examples of how to handle the Range object being nothing when `Find` isn't successful and therefore the associated Column value being 0.

You will want additional error handling for divide by 0 errors e.g. at this part

```
/ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Value
```

And this

```
/ActiveSheet(i, ColA).Value
```

Again, how you handle it is up to you.

You might choose a default value, to warn the user, to exit the sub, to On Error Resume Next to skip to the next line, to have a test before the division such

```
If ActiveSheet(i, ColA).Value = 0 Or ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ColC).Value  = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: Tried this update, now its a Run-time error 91, Object Variable not set on ColA= ValA.Column

Comment: Did you include the error handling i showed in the answer? And declare the ValA etc as Ranges? You would need error handling for each case where you are trying to find and then set e.g. ValA, ValB....

Comment: If Not Val A is nothing would mean if Val A has something? hence the Find worked?

Comment: yes. You would also need error handling for your colour index section as if nothing was found there won't be a column to use in the cell reference (it will given the value 0 which is invalid.

Comment: This results in an Overflow error on the division statement

Answer (score 0):

To do this with conditional formating, first select your data range (select the entire 4 columns):

Then, go to conditional formating > new rule...

Do a formula based condition (last option) and enter the following formula:

```
=($D1/$C1)<>($B1/$A1) 'in my case. Edit to fit your respective data columns.
```

Click on "Format" to choose your highlight options and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

*Ok, I am new to StackOverflow and VBA, but I got your code to work by changing it a little... I tested it, and it works.*

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub test()

Dim Tbl1, ValA, ValB, ValC, ValD As Range
Dim ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, i, LastRow As Long
Worksheets(1).Activate
Cells.Find("").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
Set Tbl1 = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion

Set ValA = Tbl1.Find("A")
Set ValA = Worksheets(1).Range(ValA, ValA.End(xlDown))
Set ValB = Tbl1.Find("B")
Set ValB = Worksheets(1).Range(ValB, ValB.End(xlDown))
Set ValC = Tbl1.Find("C")
Set ValC = Worksheets(1).Range(ValC, ValC.End(xlDown))
Set ValD = Tbl1.Find("D")
Set ValD = Worksheets(1).Range(ValD, ValD.End(xlDown))

LastRow = Tbl1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

ColA = ValA.Cells.Count
ColB = ValB.Cells.Count
ColC = ValC.Cells.Count
ColD = ValC.Cells.Count

'Loop

If ColA > 0 And ColB > 0 And ColC > 0 And ColD > 0 Then

    For i = 2 To LastRow

        If ValD.Cells(i).Value / ValC.Cells(i).Value <>       
ValB.Cells(i).Value / ValA.Cells(i).Value Then

            ValA.Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ValB.Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ValC.Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            ValD.Cells(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        End If

    Next i

 Else

     MsgBox "Matches weren't found for A,B,C and D in row 1."

End If

End Sub
```

Tada! Also got me thinking of how to automatically choose any number of columns... A-F for example. But the above code will fix what you are asking help on, best of luck!
-.Reverus.